# git reset --hard <sha1>. Did that delete everything?

Tags: git, github

I had a branch dev and a branch cutting-edge.

I had a commit with SHA1 id say 4356xyz on dev. I wanted that to be on cutting-edge. So I checked out cutting-edge and did

`git reset --hard 4356xyz`

Now when I do `git log` I see that history of both the branches have become same. 
Is there a way by which I can recover the previous history of cutting-edge branch before I did the reset?

Comment: What did you think `git reset --hard` would do?

Comment: I thought it would do cherry picking.. `git cherry-pick 4356xyz`. Just discovered later that would point the head to that commit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git reset --hard 4356xyz` took your `cutting-edge` branch and pointed it at that commit. If that was the same commit that `dev` was pointing at, then yes, they will share the same history because they are now pointing at the same commit.

You can inspect `git reflog` to figure out what your branch `cutting-edge` pointed to *before* you told get to point it at commit `4356xyz`.

In the future, if you want to add commits from one branch onto another, you need to either merge your branches, or cherry-pick specific commits.

To pull *just* commit `4356xyz`, you would `git checkout cutting-edge` and then `git cherry-pick 4356xyz`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use the `git reflog` command to show the history of where your branch head has been. Select the commit you want it to be, and use `git reset --hard` with that commit.